# Creating a "My Documents" browser like in the iPad iWork Apps

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, ipad, documents, ios

Keynote, Numbers, and Pages all have a top level "My Documents" browser where you can create, delete, and select for editing all of the documents you've created so far.

I'd like to create a document browser like this for an iPad app, but I am not sure where to start. I've Googled and searched here on Stackoverflow, but I haven't found any information about how to do this.

So any suggestions, links, tutorials, sample apps, or advice on where to look in Apple's documentation would be greatly appreciated.

(I am not interested in any of the import/export, or other document specific functionality, just how I'd go about creating the user interface.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550524/how-to-create-ipad-document-preview-interface-like-those-found-in-iworks-for-ipad/4581422#4581422), where I explain the process of creating the interface you want.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Omni Group's framework on [github](http://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup).

Specifically, look at the `OUIDocumentPicker` in the OmniUI folder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Ashley. It might be just what I was looking for. I've decided to hold off a bit on implementing multiple documents in the app I am working on for now. But when I come back to it this will be the first thing I'll try.