# iOS itunes app modal on ipad: seperator above scroll view

Tags: ios, ipad, quartz-graphics, modalviewcontroller

I am looking to implement a modal similar to the iTunes App on the ipad.  Here is a great screen from another post: [[iTunes style modal view controller chain (form sheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345941/itunes-style-modal-view-controller-chain-form-sheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345941/itunes-style-modal-view-controller-chain-form-sheet).

Notice the seperation of the 2 parts: the top(movie name/image/etc) and the bottom scroll view(summary/credits/etc).  I am wondering how to recreate that border, drop shadow, views or whatever that seperator is.  If you have an ipad load the itunes app and click on the title, you will see the modal draws that top frame first.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A good tutorial for doing drop shadows & gradients was written by the esteemed Ray Wenderlich, here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss which I think should cover what you're looking to do, and then some.

Fair warning, diving into Core Graphics and its cousins, Core Animation and Quartz, is a bit of a rabbit hole. It's an extremely feature-complete framework, with functions to do nearly anything. Finding those functions though can be a real challenge.

Have fun :)