# Touch to move through images

Tags: image, nsmutablearray, touch, imageview

I have an NSMutableArray of jpg images and I want to be able to touch and, moving my finger from right to left, move through the array of images in order. I've been reading about UIScrollView, but I'm not sure if this accomplishes what I am looking for. It seems to me that UIScrollView is more used for viewing an object that is too large to be displayed entirely on the screen and you need to be able to move to see every part of the object. I need to move to an entirely new image, the next image in my array. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: In principle, you need to add UIImageView instances to the scroll view and then set its content area to the collective of the ImageView objects. You can also use a PageControl to make the experience better.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly *can* use a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/) for what you want. A scroll view can be used, as you noted, to scroll an area that is too large for the screen. However, you can also use it to scroll through "pages". This is really the best way to do what you want, short of rolling your won scroll view.

There is a property of [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/), called `pagingEnabled`, which you'll want to set to `YES`. I suggest that you give it a try. Also, have a look at [the UIScrollView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/) and [the Scroll View programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html). It will tell you all that you need to know about UIScrollViews. Also, remember that for proper memory management, you'll want to only load three images at any given time. See [this answer that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550524/how-to-create-ipad-document-preview-interface-like-those-found-in-iworks-for-ipad/4581422#4581422) for more information on that, and on UIScrollViews in general.